# Adding custom field to Lightbox in header only pulls current page data, not Lightbox item data

Tags: custom-field

I'm currently using Advanced Custom Fields to create a custom field `has_the_portrait_sold` which will be indicated on my Prettyphoto / Lightbox item.

However, when I use PHP from the example (it is true or false):

```
if(get_field('has_the_portrait_sold')){
echo "The item has been sold.";
}else{
echo "The item has not been sold";
}
```

In header.php:

```
<script type text/javascript>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("a[href$='.jpg'], a[href$='.jpeg'], 
a[href$='.gif'], a[href$='.png']").prettyPhoto({
theme: 'dark_square',
show_title: true, /* true/false */
social_tools: '<?php the_title(); ?> <?php
if(get_field('has_the_portrait_sold')){
echo "do something";
}else{
echo "do something else";
}
?>'
});
});
</script>
```

However, while this may include the custom field in the lightbox as needed, it apparently only displays custom field data for the current page. I am needing custom field data to print for the current lightbox item / WordPress' image attachment.

I therefore tried including the custom field call in `post-template.php`. Please note my PHP skills are limited, I am VERY determined to make this work.

```
return apply_filters( 'wp_get_attachment_link', "<a title='$post_title'
href='$url'>$link_text</a><?php
if(get_field('has_the_portrait_sold')){
echo "do something";
}else{
echo "do something else";
}
?>", $id, $size, $permalink, $icon, $text );
}
```

I feel like I am on the right path in including the custom field call in `post-template.php` . However, I just do not have the PHP skills necessary to create the correct call. I'm wondering if someone here can help. I am very desperate, but not willing to give up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first - **YOU ARE NOT ON THE RIGHT PATH IF YOU ARE MODIFYING CORE FILES**.  If it's not in `wp-content`, **DO NOT MODIFY IT**, especially if you can honestly say "I just do not have the PHP skills necessary to XXXX".  **STAY OUT OF CORE FILES, PERIOD**.  I'm not being mean, I'm saving you the hassle of losing your changes with each WordPress update, plus the ire of WordPress developers as a whole.

You're going to have a problem the way you're going about it.  From the sound of it, you're trying to call `get_field()` in the header outside the loop, but somehow wanting it to know where in the loop it is.

Some explanation that might help: custom fields are attached to specific pages/posts (as you already know).  This means that `get_field()` will return values according to the current object in `$post` - in the header, that's the current page.  Not sure what the object in `$post` is at any given point?  Use this code chunk where you want to know:

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($post); ?>
</pre>
```

You can also swap `$post` with `$post->ID` to see which post it's working on (especially useful for seeing what posts are pulling up in a loop).

So, you'll need to register whether or not a piece is sold by checking in the loop, then perhaps attach a CSS class to the output in the loop, and use CSS to show/hide that bit.

If you're trying to do it by hooking into a function (for attachment override, for example), then put that hook into `functions.php`.  You can modify or override core functions in `functions.php` with filters and hooks - check the Codex for more info.